# Why does my element only work on float right (not left)

Tags: css, css-float

If I set `firstGroup` to `float: right`, I get two columns with the first group on the right as expected.  However, if I set it to `float: left`, I just get the following elements stuck up to the bottom of the first!

NOTE: I need to support all the way back to IE7, so no `column-count`.

Here is a dramatically simplified version of my page (I've only left the relevant block elements and only given a few sample items):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Take</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .group
        {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width: 50%;
            min-width: 530px;
        }

        .group > .group
        {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        .group > .label
        {
            display: block;
            width: 510px;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .firstGroup
        {
            float: left;
        }

        .item
        {
            display: block;
            width: 510px;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .item .label
        {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 20px;
        }

        .header textarea
        {
            display: block;
        }

        .header
        {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="main">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="header">
                    Notes :
                    <textarea name="Notes"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="group firstGroup">
                    <span class="label" style="background-color: #005588; color: white;">List 1</span>
                    <div class="group">
                        <span class="label" style="background-color: #999999; color: #000000;">Sub List 1</span>

                        <span class="item" style="background-color: #339933; color: #000000;">
                            <span class="label">Item 1</span>
                            <span class="options">
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[0].itemResultID" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />N/A</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[0].itemResultID" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[0].itemResultID" type="radio" value="2" />No</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="notes"><input type="text" name="item[0].TestNotes" value="" /></span>
                        </span>

                        <span class="item" style="background-color: #339933; color: #000000;">
                            <span class="label">Item 2</span>
                            <span class="options">
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[1].itemResultID" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />N/A</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[1].itemResultID" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[1].itemResultID" type="radio" value="2" />No</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="notes"><input type="text" name="item[1].TestNotes" value="" /></span>
                        </span>

                        <span class="item" style="background-color: #339933; color: #000000;">
                            <span class="label">Item 3</span>
                            <span class="options">
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[2].itemResultID" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />N/A</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[2].itemResultID" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[2].itemResultID" type="radio" value="2" />No</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="notes"><input type="text" name="item[2].TestNotes" value="" /></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group">
                        <span class="label" style="background-color: #999999; color: #000000;">Sub List 2</span>

                        <span class="item" style="background-color: yellow; color: #000000;">
                            <span class="label">Item 1</span>
                            <span class="options">
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[3].itemResultID" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />N/A</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[3].itemResultID" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</span>
                                <span class="option"><input name="item[3].itemResultID" type="radio" value="2" />No</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="notes"><input type="text" name="item[3].TestNotes" value="" /></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <span class="label" style="background-color: red; color: white;">List 2</span>

                    <span class="item" style="background-color: #339933; color: #000000;">
                        <span class="label">Item 1</span>
                        <span class="options">
                            <span class="option"><input name="item[4].itemResultID" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />N/A</span>
                            <span class="option"><input name="item[4].itemResultID" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</span>
                            <span class="option"><input name="item[4].itemResultID" type="radio" value="2" />No</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="notes"><input type="text" name="item[4].TestNotes" value="" /></span>
                    </span>

                    <span class="item" style="background-color: #339933; color: #000000;">
                        <span class="label">Item 2</span>
                        <span class="options">
                            <span class="option"><input name="item[5].itemResultID" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />N/A</span>
                            <span class="option"><input name="item[5].itemResultID" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</span>
                            <span class="option"><input name="item[5].itemResultID" type="radio" value="2" />No</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="notes"><input type="text" name="item[5].TestNotes" value="" /></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested in FF 8 and IE 9, both have the same behavior.

Comment: can you canfigure this on jsfiddler?

Comment: when you set float: right then that is what you expected why you change it to left ?

Comment: I want the `firstGroup` to appear on the *left* side of the screen, not the right side.  Setting `float: right` makes the `firstGroup` appear on the right side.

Comment: I just found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4968387/794234 which seems to have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should float **`.group`** and not just `.firstGroup`

Comment: That solves the problem... but does not explain why.  This does not seem to follow the documentation.

Comment: This is basic CSS. Block elements such as divs stay one below the other in the a normal flow. Floating allows us to break this pattern by having more than one block element on the same line. But for this to work as expected, they should all be floating. Not doing this creates unexpected behaviors. This rule is bent in some cases such as wrapping images around text, where that behavior proves helpful.