# Does width property affects clear?

Tags: css

I was trying to understand float and clear. I have DIV with float left and then

element cleared right.

```css
.container {
  border: solid thin #ccc;
}

.left-segment {
  float: left;
  background-color: #8FC9FF;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}


.text-clear {
  clear: right;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-segment'>I am LEFT DIV</div>
  
  <p class='text-clear'>Hey There I am P with some so called DUMMY data. And Dummy data again</p>
```

It worked as expected. P element occupied empty space left by div with left float.

But now i tried to add width to P element and P element appeared right below to floated DIV

Example -

```css
.container {
  border: solid thin #ccc;
}

.left-segment {
  float: left;
  background-color: #8FC9FF;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}


.text-clear {
  clear: right;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-segment'>I am LEFT DIV</div>
  
  <p class='text-clear'>Hey There I am P with some so called DUMMY data. And Dummy data again</p>
```

Why width is affecting clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why \`float:left\` doesn't work with a fixed width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968387/why-floatleft-doesnt-work-with-a-fixed-width)

Comment: looks on similar line, but answers were not as expected. The way @temani explained made things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, the use of clear here is useless simply because you are clearing the right and you have used `float:left`. So you will have the same output if you remove the clear.

To better understand what is happening, let's make the float element a bit transparent:

```css
.container {
  border: solid thin #ccc;
}

.left-segment {
  float: left;
  background-color: #8FC9FF;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.text-clear {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0; /*let's remove margin to avoid confusion*/
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-segment'>I am LEFT DIV</div>

  <p class='text-clear'>Hey There I am P with some so called DUMMY data. And Dummy data again</p>
</div>
```

As you can see the red div start at the top of the container and not below the floating element as you may think. If we refer to [the documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) we can read that:

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed
>   along the left or right side of its container, allowing **text and**
>   **inline elements** to wrap around it. The element is removed from the
>   normal flow of the web page, though still remaining a part of the flow
>   (in contrast to absolute positioning).

So only text will wrap around the float element and not the whole block element. In other words, your red div is place at the beginning of the container with a width of `200px` then the float element is getting above it AND it pushs the text to the bottom since it can no more push it to the left.

let's add an animation and we will better see what is happening:

```css
.container {
  border: solid thin #ccc;
}

.left-segment {
  float: left;
  background-color: #8FC9FF;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.text-clear {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {width:600px}
  to {width:100px}
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-segment'>I am LEFT DIV</div>

  <p class='text-clear'>Hey There I am P with some so called DUMMY data. And Dummy data again</p>
</div>
```

It's more clear now how the text is wrapping around the float and respecting the width of its container.

---

Now if you clear the left you will correctly clear the float element and your red div will start under it:

```css
.container {
  border: solid thin #ccc;
}

.left-segment {
  float: left;
  background-color: #8FC9FF;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.text-clear {
  clear: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  animation: change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {width: 600px}
  to {width: 100px}
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-segment'>I am LEFT DIV</div>

  <p class='text-clear'>Hey There I am P with some so called DUMMY data. And Dummy data again</p>
</div>
```