# Understanding wrapping of text around floating div

Tags: html, css

I just watched this video to understand how floats work in CSS

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xara4Z1b18I`

Following is my code

index.html

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box red"></div>
        <div class="box yellow"></div>
        <div class="box green"></div>
        <p>This is a block element</p>
        <p>This is another block element</p>
        <p>And another</p>
        <p>Yet another</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}


.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;

}


.green{
  background-color: green;
  float: left;


}
```

The output that I get is this

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

What my doubt is :

On floating red, as expected yellow gets hidden, green shifts up.
On floating yellow, it moves to the right of red, green gets hidden.
But on floating green, why does text wrap around the green. Shouldn't it have been hidden behind the red div?

Comment: related question with some examples and explanation, almost the same as yours : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299426/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/53461888/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932252/8620333 (TL;DR from all of them: float will never overlap text and text will always wrap around float)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does width property affects clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931584/does-width-property-affects-clear)

Answer (score 0):

Text is treated differently and is made to wrap around floated elements.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

See this fiddle.  As soon as you add text, it is treated differently than non-textual elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/bgsotpvk/20/

```css
p {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: .5;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box yellow"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>


  <p>This is a block element</p>
  <p>This is another block element</p>
  <p>And another</p>
  <p>Yet another</p>
</div>
```